# namespace in php

Tags: php-5.3

```
<?php
namespace foo;
use My\Full\Classname as Another;

// this is the same as use My\Full\NSname as NSname
use My\Full\NSname;

// importing a global class
use ArrayObject;

$obj = new namespace\Another; // instantiates object of class foo\Another
$obj = new Another; // instantiates object of class My\Full\Classname
NSname\subns\func(); // calls function My\Full\NSname\subns\func
$a = new ArrayObject(array(1)); // instantiates object of class ArrayObject
// without the "use ArrayObject" we would instantiate an object of class foo\ArrayObject
?>
```

Please help me with this.

What is the meaning of `use My\Full\Classname as Another;`

Comment: Its just saying to use a class called `Another` from namespace `foo` thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats an alias. Every time you refer `Another` as a (relative) namespace, or classname, it gets resolved to `\My\Full\Classname`

```
$x = new Another;
echo get_class($x); // "\My\Full\Classname"
$y = new Another\Something;
echo get_class($y); // "\My\Full\Classname\Something"
```

Identifiers starting with a namespace separator `\` are full-qualified names. If it's missing, the identifiers are resolved against the current namespace and against the alias definitions defined by `use` (in this order) (except for identifiers in `use` and `namespace`: They are always full-qualified).

[PHP-Manual: Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: so ..\My\Full is namespace and Classname is class in that namespace?

Comment: It depends :) `use My\Full\Classname as Another` just more a kind kind of prefix alias. If you type `new Another;`, or `new Another\Something\Different` in both cases it will replace (literally) `Another` with the prefix you defined (what leads to `\My\Full\Classname`, or `\My\Full\Classname\Something\Different`).

Comment: but if `Classname` in `use My\Full\Classname as Another` is not an class then how can we create object of Another (`new Another;`)

Comment: @PoonamBhatt We cannot, but thats not a problem from the use of namespace. You cannot instanciate a class, that does not exists, since ever (`new IDontExists;` => `Fatal error: Class 'IDontExists' not found`). Namespaces don't make a difference here: It behaves like before.